# form submitting 0 to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, pdo

I have an html form with item and amount entries and I want the values in them to be stored in local storage and xampp, I have succeeded in submiting to localstorage however the form submits nothing in xampp in a column for item and 0 in the column of amount
here is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>ICT specialists</title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="ICT_Logo-01.png">
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Daily transactions at ICT specialists</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <h4>Your balance</h4>
        <h1 id="balance"></h1>
        <div class="inc-exp-container">
        <div>
            <h4>income</h4>
            <p id="money-plus" class="money plus"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>expense</h4>
            <p id="money-minus" class="money minus"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3>History</h3>
    <div class="shows">
        <ion-icon name="menu-outline" id="showLi"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="close-outline" id="hideLi"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <ul id="list" class="list"></ul>
    <h3>add new transation</h3>
    <form action="sales.php" method="post" id="form">
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="">date</label>
            <input type="text" id="date" name="date">
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="text">item</label>
            <input type="text" id="text" name="item" placeholder="please enter the item..." autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="amount">amount <br />(negative=expense, positive=income)</label>
            <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="please enter the amount..." autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Add transation</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <div class="footerTxt">copyright &copy <span id="dated">2022</span</div>
    <div class="footerRyt">
        <a href="http://www.sydotech.com/" target="_blank">ict specialists | sydotech</a>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
  .footer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: deepskyblue !important;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
  }
  .footer .footerTxt{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .footer .footerRyt a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #fff !important;
  }
</style>
<ion-icon name="arrow-up-outline" id="icons"></ion-icon>

<script src="sales.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"> 
</script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my php

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=sales','root','');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST'){
    $item = $_POST['item'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("insert into transaction 
                                    (item,amount) 
                            values (:item,:amount)");
    $statement->bindValue(':item', $item );
    $statement->bindValue(':amount', $amount );

    $statement->execute();
    header('Location: sales.html');
}
```

here is my javascript file

```
const balance = document.getElementById("balance");
const money_plus = document.getElementById("money-plus");
const list = document.getElementById("list");
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const text = document.getElementById("text");
const amount = document.getElementById("amount");
const money_minus = document.getElementById("money-minus");
let showLi = document.getElementById("showLi");
let hideLi = document.getElementById('hideLi');

const localStorageTransations = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("transations"));

let transations =
localStorage.getItem("transations") !== null ? localStorageTransations : [];

//add transation
function addTransation() {
    // e.preventDefault();
    if (text.value.trim() === "" || amount.value.trim() === "") {
        text.placeholder = "PLEASE SOME TEXT";
        text.style.backgroundColor = "#ccc";
        text.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        amount.placeholder = "ENTER AMOUNT";
        amount.style.backgroundColor = "#ccc";
        amount.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    } else {
        const transation = {
            id: genenrateID(),
            text: text.value,
            amount: +amount.value,
        };
        transations.push(transation);
        addTransationDOM(transation);
        updateValues();
        updateLocalStorage();
        text.value = "";
        amount.value = "";
    }
}
//generate id
function genenrateID() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000);
}
//add transations to dom list
function addTransationDOM(transation) {
    //get sign
    const sign = transation.amount < 0 ? "-" : "+";
    const item = document.createElement("li");
    //add class based on value
    item.classList.add(transation.amount < 0 ? "minus" : "plus");
    item.innerHTML = `${transation.text} <span>${sign}${Math.abs(transation.amount)}</span> 
        <button class="delete-btn" onclick="removeTransation(${transation.id})">x</button>`;
    list.appendChild(item);
    item.style.display="none";
    hideLi.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        item.style.display = 'none';
        hideLi.style.display = "none";
        showLi.style.display = "block";
    });
    showLi.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        item.style.display = 'block';
        hideLi.style.display = "block";
        showLi.style.display = "none";
    })
}
// ********hide list******


// ********hide list end******
//update the balance
function updateValues() {
    const amounts = transations.map((transation) => transation.amount);
    const total = amounts.reduce((acc, item) => (acc += item), 0).toFixed(0);
    const income = amounts
    .filter((item) => item > 0)
    .reduce((acc, item) => (acc += item), 0)
    .toFixed(0);
    const expense = (
        amounts.filter((item) => item < 0).reduce((acc, item) => (acc += item), 0) * -1).toFixed(0);

    balance.innerText = `UgShs: ${total}`;
    money_plus.innerText = `UgShs: ${income}`;
    money_minus.innerText = `UgShs: ${expense}`;
}

//remove
function removeTransation(id) {
    transations = transations.filter((transation) => transation.id !== id); 
    updateLocalStorage();
    init();
}

//updatelocal storage
function updateLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem("transations", JSON.stringify(transations));
}

function init() {
    list.innerHTML = "";
    transations.forEach(addTransationDOM);
    updateValues();
}

init();
form.addEventListener("submit", addTransation);
// *********date calculation********
let date =document.getElementById('date');
date.value = new Date().toDateString();

// *********ionicons*******88
let icon = document.getElementById('icons');
window.onscroll = ()=>{
    if(window.scrollY >=100){
        icon.style.display = 'block';
        icon.style.position = 'fixed';
    }else{
        icon.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
icon.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    window.scrollTo({top:0, behavior:"smooth"})
})

let span11 = document.getElementById('dated');
span11.innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
```

Comment: It appears that you want to update both the localstorage and the db ?

Comment: Generally if using`{}` the inner content should be indented. This is hard to read.

Comment: what is hard to read

Comment: ___It was all hard to read!___ Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code** You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.